# Difference in two Normal Distributions?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am unsure what I should do if I have two Normally Distributed variables with known parameters and I want to find the probability that one of these variables is greater than the other. Should I use the distribution of differences of the two normal variables, as is shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html)?

Comment: If you have the [*parameters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter) of the two distributions, you know immediately whether one of the *parameters* is greater than the other - it's a fixed quantity. Do you mean that (given the two distributions) you need the probability that an observation from one distribution is greater than an observation from the other?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, the latter. I need to know the probability that an observation from one distribution is greater than an observation from the other. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that information. For the new question to be answerable, you'll need some kind of information/assumption about their *joint distribution*. Are you prepared to assume independence? (That, with the marginal distributions you appear to have, would be enough to specify their joint distribution.)

Comment: @Glen_b The two distributions can be assumed to be independent. May I ask why we need to consider the Joint Distribution? And what then needs to be done with it?

Comment: The probability that $X_1>X_2$ depends on the joint distribution, not just the marginal distributions (I can make $X_1$ and $X_2$ normal and yet get a very different collection of answers as I vary their copula), so you need to consider the joint distribution. Given the joint distribution, you compute from it the required probability. If they're jointly normal, you'd usually do it by computing the distribution of the difference and comparing to 0. The given answer assumed independence *without even checking if that assumption was justified*. Since you now say that's okay, that answer is fine.

Comment: I was editing to correct another terminological error in the question, so I folded your edit into the original wording of the question (which as it stood was misleading). Better for later readers to ask a clear question than ask a misleading one and then try to correct the impression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this. This is not my own answer from from math.stackexchange, but it may be useful to duplicate it here: [Probability of a point taken from a certain normal distribution will be greater than a point taken from another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/probability-of-a-point-taken-from-a-certain-normal-distribution-will-be-greater).

Quoting [Shai Covo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2810/shai-covo):

Suppose that $X_1 \sim {\rm N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim {\rm N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ are independent. Then,
$$
{\rm P}(X_1  > X_2 ) = {\rm P}(X_1  - X_2  > 0) = 1 - {\rm P}(X_1  - X_2  \le 0).
$$
Now, by independence, $X_1 - X_2$ is normally distributed with mean
$$
\mu := {\rm E}(X_1 - X_2) = \mu_1 - \mu_2
$$
and variance
$$
\sigma^2 := {\rm Var}(X_1 - X_2) = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\frac{{X_1  - X_2  - \mu}}{{\sigma}} \sim {\rm N}(0,1),
$$
and so
$$
{\rm P}(X_1  - X_2  \le 0) = {\rm P}\bigg(\frac{{X_1  - X_2  - \mu }}{\sigma } \le \frac{{0 - \mu }}{\sigma }\bigg) = \Phi \Big(  \frac{-\mu }{\sigma }\Big),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the distribution function of the ${\rm N}(0,1)$ distribution. Thus,
$$
{\rm P}(X_1  > X_2 )  = 1 - {\rm P}(X_1  - X_2  \le 0) = 1 - \Phi \Big(  \frac{-\mu }{\sigma }\Big).
$$

Comment: Policy on duplicates between sites? I have no idea. Amusingly there's a bit of "does that belong on cross validated" discussion on the linked question. The questioner should bear in mind in general that his stats questions may be answered on the Mathematics site already (also on mathoverflow, but seems unlikely).

Comment: Thanks a lot. My math is very rusty at the moment and I was just wondering what _distribution function_ actually means here? Does it refer to the CDF?

Comment: @Yep, it's the CDF, which is the area under the graph below (-mu/sigma). What we've done in this penultimate step is start out with the probability we're interested in, adding things to both side to put it in terms of the thing we know the distribution of. So x(1)<x(2) while ((x(1)-x(2)-mu)/sigma) < (-mu/sigma), which is something tables or a computer can tell us.

Comment: Thanks. So, I'm looking at determining $1 - \Phi \Big(  \frac{-\mu }{\sigma }\Big)$ through Matlab and am planning on using [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/normcdf.html) function. However, I am unsure what _x_ should should be in this case.

Comment: It seems like normcdf(x) does the trick for N(0,1), so nordcdf(0) would return 0.5, for example. So 1-normcdf(−μσ) is what you want.

Comment: I see. So, the probability that one Normally Distributed value is greater than another Normally Distributed value (i.e.${\rm P}(X_1  > X_2 )$) is just a number and _not a Distribution_? Thanks again.

Comment: Probabilities are always real numbers between zero and one.

Comment: @Zen I just appear to be getting one or zero when using this method, where if $\mu_1>\mu_2$ I get ${\rm P}(X_1  > X_2 ) = 1$ and if $\mu_1<\mu_2$ I get ${\rm P}(X_1  > X_2 ) = 0$. Is this as expected? Thanks.

Comment: @user131983 Maybe, depends on the distributions. I will tell you that it isn't actually 1 and 0 and that those values have been rounded. Zen is simply making a point about how probabilities map to [0,1].

Comment: @NathanCooper Thanks for the reply. I think I may have a problem then as I am getting exactly 1 and exactly 0. Would you know why this might be the case?

Comment: @user131983 Bit late to help you maybe, but you're not getting "exactly" 0 or 1, you're using a computer and they have a certain amount of precision. It really doesn't matter, just say one is 0 and the other is 1 (to 3s.f. or something). Here's some Matlab advice on precision in case it matters: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/MATLAB/MATLABformat.htmlb